Why is my ajax call is failling and going to .fail function
i would appreciate any help with this issue i am making an ajax call fro. welcome.php file and its failing and i cant figure out the error.
i have made similar calls for diffrenet project and they succeeded
ajax call:
//on clicking search Comp button

 $("#searchBtn2").on('click',function() {

        $.ajax({
            url:"welcome-ajax.php",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                GetPipelines: "GetPipelines",
                PCid :"JS-59",
            }

        }).done(function(Result){

            if (Result == "200" || Result == 200) {
                console.log(Result);
            } else {
                console.log(Result);
                document.getElementById("addBarcode").value="Result[1]";
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            var error = textStatus;

            var details = errorThrown;

            //700 is a Database connection error
            if (xhr.status == 700) {

                error = "Could not connect to the Databse";

                details = "The database is missing - OR - the server is refusing to connect/is down.";

                // 701 is a query execution error

            } else if (xhr.status == 701) {

                error = "Could not find the specified table in the databse.";

                details = "The table might have been deleted or moved to somewhere else.";

            }

            var subStr = xhr.responseText.match(":(.*).");
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            var response = div.innerText;

            msg = " Oh snap! -  an error occured while adding the device. You can find the details in the <a href=\"log.php?Status=" + xhr.status + "&StatusText=" + xhr.statusText + "&Response=" + response + "&Error=" + error + "&Detail=" + details + "\"  target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">log</a>.";

            console.log("Status=" + xhr.status + "&StatusText=" + xhr.statusText + "&Response=" + response + "&Error=" + error + "&Detail=" + details);
        });
    });

ajax code:
if (isset($_POST['GetPipelines'])) {

    $PCid = $_POST['PCid'];
    $Query = "SELECT * FROM db_runtimes.master_pl_time_actual_avg where System Like '%JS-59%' ;"

    $AllRecords = array();
    if (!$Result = mysqli_query($InventoryCon, $Query)) {

        header('HTTP/1.1 701 Query Execution Error');

        throw new ErrorException($InventoryCon->error, 701);

        exit();

    } else {

        while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {

            $RowArray = array();
            $RowArray[] = $Row['Pipeline'];
            $RowArray[] = $Row['num_jobs'];
            $RowArray[] = $Row['num_jobs'];
            $RowArray[] = $Row['num_jobs'];
            $RowArray[] = $Row['num_jobs'];
            $AllRecords[] = $RowArray;

        }
        $output = array(
            "draw" => 25,
            "recordsTotal" => mysqli_num_rows($Result),
            "recordsFiltered" => 25,
            "data" => $AllRecords
        );

        //echo json_encode($AllRecords);

        echo 200;

    }

    mysqli_close($InventoryCon);
}

error:
Status=200&StatusText=OK&Response=&Error=parsererror&Detail=SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'i', ..."

if (isset("... is not valid JSON

i was expenting the call to be made and get a result from ajax call
but every tile .fail function is being called

It's not executing the PHP code, it's returning the source code. Do you have <?php at the beginning of the script?
